# Rebuilding a CSS, what tools should I be using

Tags: css

I have an existing CSS and would love to revamp it, what CSS tools should I be using to do this?

I have an existing web application that already has tons of CSS, but want a total revamp.

Tools and suggestions about how to do this would be great.

Comment: What platform?  There may be some options that integrate a bit better than others for you as well.

Comment: What do you want to revamp exactly?

Comment: A whole website. I can use any tools, I am open as long as I can do things quick and easy. The site itself is in Django.

Answer (score 3):

your best option is a simple text editor, a good CSS book and Google.

no sarcasm or anything intended. if you want to revamp your CSS, learn CSS and write it yourself. no tool will ever produce the same quality as hand written CSS.

Comment: +1 cuz I agree that doing it old school is the best way to go, but some editors like Stylizer or DreamWeaver have some decent formatting engines that help keep things organized.

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to say you should just use a standard text editor and the refresh button on your browser. Visual Studio has auto complete for CSS styles so that could help.

Alternatively you could try something like this

[Stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/)

but personally I think its overkill

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do a "total revamp" unless I had a fantastic reason to do so. That being said, the only tools I would use is a standard editor with syntax-highlighting (like **[intype](http://intype.info/home/index.php)**), and **[firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)**. Avoid wysiwyg editors like the plague! They will write horrible markup/css, and you'll find yourself wanting to do yet another revamp down the road. Learn to write solid styling rules, and avoid verbosity.

Another interesting firefox plugin that works in conjuction with firebug is **[firediff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13179)**. This will help you keep track of the changes you're making in firebug, to carry them over into your project files.

I would also keep the major browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE7/8) opened in parallel to one-another, for constant testing. You'll meet some designers who say "Get it working in Firefox, then test later in IE," but I call that nonsense - test it in all, all the time, and you won't have to figure out solutions for one in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simpel text editor, with some syntax highlighting.

Read up on, Object Oriented CSS.

Slideshow about this: http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox, install the "Firebug" and "Web Developer" Add On. They are invaluable when you need to explore the current setup.

You'll get a "Inspect Element" feature with Firebug that also allows you to inspect small changes rapidly.

Use (search for) reset stylesheets for a good start; 
and really go for the semantics of your content, not just pure CSS effects.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Yaml](http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html) for creating CSS based layout. It's not a "tool" to revamp existing CSS files but comes with a lot of examples and predesigned CSS files to design floating layouts with CSS (and helps to add all those terrible browser-specific hacks to get cross-browser working pages). Not sure if this could be interesting for your purpose, just take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Structually, you could try using a grid layout like [960](http://960.gs/).

If you'd like to try a CSS framework, you could use something like [cssscaffold](http://github.com/anthonyshort/csscaffold) or [compass](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/).

You may be interested in trying the "[object oriented css](http://www.google.com/search?q=object+oriented+css)" style moving forward.

Your original question is a little non-specific, though.